# Thermal printer does not print until buffer is full

Tags: printer, serial-port

I have an Epson TM-T88II receipt printer, with a DB-25 connector. I connected it to my Debian machine with a pl2303 USB converter.  I configured the printer using the following command:

```
stty -F /dev/usbTTY0 9600 ixon raw
```

Printing single lines does not work, such as

```
echo "Hello world!" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but printing large amounts of text works, with the following command:

```
yes > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So the printer does work, but it seems that it starts printing when the buffer is full.

How can I print individual lines of text or images, without first fulling the buffer?

Comment: It isn't clear what the question is.  It sounds like the printer is designed to print a "page" rather than a line.  Have you checked the documentation to verify that it can print a line at a time (and if so, how to do it)?  A lot of thermal printers do work that way.

Comment: Ah I forgot to add the actual question. I have another receipt printer connected to USB, which works fine with individual lines. They both implement the same protocol for printing, ESC/PoS.

Comment: I'm assuming printers, interfaces and programs are identical for both printers. The printer has some DIP switches, for some of which the manual says "do not change". Compare the switch settings in the 2 printers.They're under a cover at the bottom of the printer.

Comment: Both printers are not identical, the one that does work (Wincor Nixdorf TH320+) is directly connected to the USB port, the printer that does not work (Epson TM-T88II) has a DB-25->DB-9->USB conversion to the computer.

Comment: Any software differences? Does the hello world command print on the Wincor printer?

Comment: Yes, the Wincor does everything I want, including bitmaps. The Epson printer does only print something when I try to print a large amount of text.